# proving limit $ \lim_{x\to a}x^4 = a^4 $

Tags: calculus, limits

I know to prove this limit: $ \lim_{x\to a}x^2= a^2 $ since I only need to bound the term $x+a$ I can use the triangle inequality. but how would I prove this limit, since I have two terms $x+a$ and $x^2+a^2$ along with the $x-a$ that I need? I don't know how to deal with $x^2+a^2$ at all, I would really like some hints please.

Answer (score 2):

In general, write
$x^n-a^n
=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+...+a^{n-1}) $.

You can bound the right -hand expression.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can prove is that $f(x)=x$ is continuous and that the product of continuous functions is continuous (with the limit of the product being the product of the limits). This would make it very simple to prove even more generally that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{x^n}=a^n$ for $n$ a positive integer.

Comment: I think I need to use the epsilon-delta proof since that's what I'm going to be asked on an exam..

Comment: ah, I see.  Then I would use Marty Cohen's method.